# Не работает static и медиа в django

Tags: django

**urls.py** :

[image: urls.py]

**settings.py(static)** :

[image: settings.py(static)]

**settings.py(media)** :

[image: settings.py(media)]

python3.9 manage.py collectstatic - обновлял.

Супер юзер есть. Не работает только изображения в магазине и на главной странице фон

[image: index]
[image: shop]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: как выводите? чему равен DEBUG